# Julia "strange" behaviour using fill() and .+=

Tags: sum, julia, broadcast, in-place, arrayofarrays

I observe an unexpected behaviour for ".+=" in my code (it's probably just me, I'm rather new to Julia). Consider the following example:

```
julia> b = fill(zeros(2,2),1,3)
       1×3 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}:
       [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]

julia> b[1] += ones(2,2)
       2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
       1.0  1.0
       1.0  1.0

julia> b
       1×3 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}:
       [1.0 1.0; 1.0 1.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]

julia> b[2] .+= ones(2,2)
       2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
       1.0  1.0
       1.0  1.0

julia> b
       1×3 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}:
       [1.0 1.0; 1.0 1.0]  [1.0 1.0; 1.0 1.0]  [1.0 1.0; 1.0 1.0]
```

As it can be seen, the last command changed not only the value of b[2] but also of b[3], while b[1] remains the same as before (*), as we can confirm running:

```
julia> b[2] .+= ones(2,2)
       2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
       2.0  2.0
       2.0  2.0

julia> b
       1×3 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}:
       [1.0 1.0; 1.0 1.0]  [2.0 2.0; 2.0 2.0]  [2.0 2.0; 2.0 2.0]
```

Now, using simply "+=" instead I can obtain the behaviour I would have expected also for ".+=", that is:

```
julia> b = fill(zeros(2,2),1,3); b[2]+=ones(2,2); b
       1×3 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}:
       [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [1.0 1.0; 1.0 1.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]
```

Can anyone explain me why does it happen? I can use of course just +=, or maybe something different from an Array of Arrays, but since I'm striving for speed (I have a code that needs to perform these operations millions of times, and on much larger matrices) and .+= is considerably faster I would like to understad if I can still exploit this feature.
Thank you all in advance!

EDIT: (*) apparently only because b[1] was not zero. If I run:

```
julia> b = fill(zeros(2,2),1,3); b[2]+=ones(2,2);
julia> b[1] .+= 10 .*ones(2,2); b
       [10.0 10.0; 10.0 10.0]  [1.0 1.0; 1.0 1.0]  [10.0 10.0; 10.0 10.0]
```

you can see that only the zero-values are changed. This beats me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because of the combination of several factors. Let's try and make things clearer.

First, `b = fill(zeros(2,2),1,3)` does not create a new `zeros(2,2)` for each element of `b`; instead it creates one 2x2 array of zeros, and sets all elements of `b` to that unique array. In short, this line behaves equivalently to

```
z = zeros(2,2)
b = Array{Array{Float64,2},2}(undef, 1, 3)
for i in eachindex(b)
    b[i] = z
end
```

therefore, modifying `z[1,1]` or any of the `b[i,j][1,1]` would modify the other values as well. To illustrate this:

```
julia> b = fill(zeros(2,2),1,3)
1×3 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}:
 [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]

# All three elements are THE SAME underlying array
julia> b[1] === b[2] === b[3]
true

# Mutating one of them mutates the others as well
julia> b[1,1][1,1] = 42
42

julia> b
1×3 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}:
 [42.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [42.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [42.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]
```

Second, `b[1] += ones(2,2)` is equivalent to `b[1] = b[1] + ones(2,2)`. This implies a succession of operations:

1. a new array (let's call it `tmp`) is created to hold the sum of `b[1]` and `ones(2,2)`
2. `b[1]` is rebound to that new array, thereby losing its connection to `z` (or all other elements of `b`.

This is a variation on the classical theme that although both involve `=` signs in their notations, mutation and assignment are not the same thing. Again, to illustrate:

```
julia> b = fill(zeros(2,2),1,3)
1×3 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}:
 [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]  [0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0]

# All elements are THE SAME underlying array
julia> b[1] === b[2] === b[3]
true

# But that connection is lost when `b[1]` is re-bound (not mutated) to a new array
julia> b[1] = ones(2,2)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

# Now b[1] is no more the same underlying array as b[2]
julia> b[1] === b[2]
false

# But b[2] and b[3] still share the same array (they haven't be re-bound to anything else)
julia> b[2] === b[3]
true
```

Third, `b[2] .+= ones(2,2)` is a different beast altogether. It does not imply re-binding anything to a newly created array; instead, it mutates the array `b[2]` in place. It effectively behaves like:

```
for i in eachindex(b[2])
    b[2][i] += 1  # or b[2][i] = b[2][i] + 1
end
```

Neither `b` itself nor even `b[2]` is re-bound to anything, only elements of it are modified in place. And in your example this affects `b[3]` as well, since both `b[2]` and `b[3]` are bound to the same underlying array.

Answer (score 1):

Becasue `b` is filled with *the same* matrix, not 3 identical matrices. `.+=` change the content of the matrix, thus all content in `b` are changed. `+=` on the other hand, create a new matrix and assign it back to b[1]. To see this, you can use the `===` operator:

```
b = fill(zeros(2,2),1,3)
b[1] === b[2] # true
b[1] += zeros(2, 2) # a new matrix is created and assigned back to b[1]
b[1] == b[2] # true, they are all zeros
b[1] === b[2] # false, they are not the same matrix
```

There is actually an example in the help message of `fill` function pointing out exactly this problem. You can find it by running `?fill` in the REPL.

```
  ...

  If x is an object reference, all elements will refer to the same object:

  julia> A = fill(zeros(2), 2);
  
  julia> A[1][1] = 42; # modifies both A[1][1] and A[2][1]
  
  julia> A
  2-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
   [42.0, 0.0]
   [42.0, 0.0]
```

There are various ways to create an array of independent matrices. One is using list comprehension:

```
c = [zeros(2,2) for _ in 1:1, _ in 1:3]
c[1] === c[2] # false
```